# SSRS report Display monthwise

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Below is my sql table,

```
Month Input Output

Jan-12  10     8
Feb-12  23     6
1-Mar    8     5
```

I need to display like this in SSRS

Jan 2012

Input

10

Output

8

Feb 2012

Input

23

Output

6

Mar 2012

Input

8

Output

5

How to design the report using SSRS

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Have you tried to create it? Are you running into specific problems?

Answer (score 0):

Drop a table onto the report body canvas. Set the Dataset name property to the dataset that returns that data.

Right click the Detail row icon (it looks like three horizontal lines) on the left of the report object. Select Insert Row Below. Do this 3 more times.

You now have 5 rows.

Expand the Datasets object (normally docked on the left) to display the fields in the dataset. Drag the month field to the cell on the top row, write the text "Input" in the cell on the second row, drag the input field to the cell on the third row, write the text "Output" in the cell on the fourth row and drag the output field to the cell on the fifth row.

Run your report.